# MongoDB aggregation group simultaneously

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents stored in mongodb like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("abc"),
  teams: [{
    _id: ObjectId("aaa"),
    points: 10
  }, {
    _id: ObjectId("bbb"),
    points: 20
  }],
  players: [{
    hints: 2,
    team: ObjectId("aaa")
  }, {
    hints: 3,
    team: ObjectId("bbb")
  }]
}
```

Given a set of documents, I want to extract team points and the sum of it's players hints. Basically, I want to get something like:

```
[{
  team: aaa,
  points: 10,
  hints: 2
}, {
  team: bbb,
  points: 20,
  hints: 3
}]
```

Where points is the sum of the "points" gotten by the team in each document, and "hints" is the sum of the hints gotten by it's players.
I'm able to achieve this in two queries:

```
db.data.aggregate([ {$unwind: { "$players" }, 
                    {$group: { _id: "$players.team", hints: { $sum: "$player.hints" } } }])
```

```
[{ team: aaa, hints: 2 },{ team: bbb, hints: 3 }]
```

```
db.data.aggregate([ {$unwind: { "$teams" }, 
                    {$group: { _id: "$teams._id", points: { $sum: "$teams.points" } } }])
```

```
[{ team: aaa, points: 10 },{ team: bbb, points: 20 }]
```

Any idea to achieve this with only one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right way with your 2 queries, and you can use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to apply them in one query. After that, you need to concat arrays, then unwind and group by team id.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "points": [
        {
          $unwind: "$teams"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$teams._id",
            points: {
              $sum: "$teams.points"
            }
          }
        },

      ],
      "hints": [
        {
          $unwind: "$players"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$players.team",
            hints: {
              $sum: "$players.hints"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      merged: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$points",
          "$hints"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$merged"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$merged._id",
      points: {
        $max: "$merged.points"
      },
      hints: {
        $max: "$merged.hints"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It will output exactly what you want.

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X1gOnrKcTqe)